# Generating QR code using Google API in Excel, the QR code is not generating on another spreadsheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, google-api, vba

I found this neat spreadsheet that will generate a QR code in excel via Google API.

The website is below:
https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/generate-qrcode-with-excel

The link to the downloadable spreadsheet is below:
https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/generate-qrcode-with-excel/qr_code_udf.xlsm?attredirects=0&d=1

The issue I am having is that I copied the spreadsheet into another workbook.
Initially it didn't work until I also copied the GoogleAPI module into that work book as well. The QR code will generate in the copied spreadsheet.
However, what I am trying to do is generate the QR code in the same workbook but in another spreadsheet.

It errors out.

=URL_QRCode_SERIES("qr_code_1",J7:N7,,"qrCode")

I am using this formula in the spreadsheet that I am trying to get the QR barcode image to generate in but it errors out and shows this error:

#VALUE

Can't figure out what is wrong.
The value I am trying get a QR code for is using the concatenate command and it's in several merged cell columns as shown in formula above.

It generates qr codes successfully for any other single cell column value in that spreadsheet. So I'm wondering if I need to change the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
The formula below works:

=URL_QRCode_SERIES("qr_code_1",J7,,"qrCode")

Even though cell J7 through N7 are merged as one,
I just had to select the merged cell and it input J7 into the formula.
Then the QR bar code generates successfully.

I also discovered that I don't need the copied QRcode spreadsheet.
The GoogleAPI module in excel VBA is good enough as long as it's part of the workbook you are working in.